# Merging sorted lists without comparison key

Tags: algorithm

Say we have the following lists:

```
list 1: x, y, z
list 2: w, x
list 3: u
```

And we want to merge them such that the order among each individual list is respected. A solution for the above problem might be `w, x, y, z, u`.

This problem is easy if we have a comparison key (e.g. string comparison; a < z), as this gives us a reference to any element's position relative to other elements in the combined list. But what about the case when we don't have a key? For the above problem, we could restate the problem as follows:

```
x < y AND y < z AND w < x where x, y, z, w, u are in {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}
```

The way I'm currently solving this type of problem is to model the problem as a constraint satisfaction problem -- I run the [AC3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AC-3_algorithm) arc consistency algorithm to eliminate inconsistent values, and then run a recursive backtracking algorithm to make the assignments. This works fine, but it seems like overkill.

Is there a general algorithm or simpler approach to confront this type of problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Construct a graph with a node for every letter in your lists.

   ```
   x    y    z


   w    u
   ```
2. Add a directed edge from letter X to letter Y for every pair of consecutive letters in any list.

   ```
   x -> y -> z
   ^
   |
   w    u
   ```
3. [Topologically sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) the graph nodes to obtain a final list that satisfies all your constraints.

   If there were ever a cycle in your graph, the topological sorting algorithm would detect that cycle, revealing a contradiction in the constraints induced by your original lists.

Comment: This is such an elegant solution. Love it! I'll accept your answer shortly.